# Apache - unset a directive

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, httpd, httpd.conf

Is there a way to "unset" an arbitrary Apache directive such as by repeating it verbatim but with `Unset` or something in front of it?

For example let's say at the server config level I have:

```
ScriptAliasMatch "^/cgi-bin(.*)" "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin$1"
```

At for one of the VirtualHosts I'd like to be able to put something like the following:

```
Unset ScriptAliasMatch "^/cgi-bin(.*)" "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin$1"
```

If there's a specific approach for this directive that I'm missing, I'm interested in that as well (the best I can think of is to block access to that pattern via mod_rewrite), but I'm especially interested in whether there is a way to unset as that might be handy to know for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to move the directive from the server level to the virtualhost level, if the server-wide setting proves unacceptable for a vhost.

Use a default `Include` in every vhost and omit it in the vhosts where you deviate from the norm.

The new [`<If>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if) (httpd 2.4) might be an option too.

Comment: `<If>`  can appear in the server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess contexts and the poster is using `ScriptAliasMatch` in the server config context so I think `<If>` would work.

Comment: Bah, looked at the wrong line in the quick reference. Thanks for catching this.